#  Why "\" gives error while storing it in string in PHP?

Tags: php

My string looks like:

```
$fullPath = $dirName . "/" . $file;
```

If I replace / with \, it gives error:

> Expecting identifier or variable

I want to store in the latter way itself. How to override anything coming in between?

Comment: by the way for file and directory slashes, you might want to look at the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR - a PHP constant which is platform defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\` is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). It is a special character used to define either [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) or to escape [string-delimiters if you want to use them in the string itself](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

The correct usage is to escape the escape character like this: `\\`. This will tell the parser the you wanted the literal backslash and not the special meaning of it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the slash: `$fullPath = $dirName . "\\" . $file;`

Answer (score 2):

You need  `"\\"` because `\` is an escape character.

Comment: That's odd, because I could. I'll try it \\ .

Comment: i tried "\\" and it didnt work .. maybe cause i didnt mark it as code or something

Answer (score 0):

You might use apostrophes to denote a non-parsed string:

```
$fullPath = $dirName . '\' . $file;
```