# How do you make a string in PHP with a backslash in it?

Tags: php

I need a backslash to be a part of a string. How can I do it?

Comment: *(reference)* [Strings](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why "\" gives error while storing it in string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673186/why-gives-error-while-storing-it-in-string-in-php)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When the backslash `\` does not escape the terminating quote of the string or otherwise create a valid escape sequence (in double quoted strings), then either of these work to produce one backslash:

```
$string = 'abc\def';
$string = "abc\def";
//
$string = 'abc\\def';
$string = "abc\\def";
```

When escaping the next character would cause a parse error (terminating quote of the string) or a valid escape sequence (in double quoted strings) then the backslash needs to be escaped:

```
$string = 'abcdef\\';
$string = "abcdef\\";

$string = 'abc\012';
$string = "abc\\012";
```

Comment: In this particular example the backlash could be singly. It's nevertheless good practice to escape it. But for single quotes alike.

Comment: For single quotes this won't work if the backslash is at the end of the string. Using double backslash in single quotes works in all scenarios - the latter example is better no matter what the quote type.

Answer (score 51):

*Short answer*:

Use two backslashes.

*Long answer*:

You can sometimes use a single backslash, but sometimes you need two. When you can use a single backslash depends on two things:

- whether your string is surrounded by single quotes or double quotes and
- the character immediately following the backslash.

If you have a double quote string the backslash is treated as an escape character in many cases so it is best to always escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
$s = "foo\\bar"
```

In a single quoted string backslashes will be literal unless they are followed by either a single quote or another backslash. So to output a single backslash with a single quoted string you can normally write this:

```
$s = 'foo\bar'
```

But to output two backslashes in a row you need this:

```
$s = 'foo\\\\bar'
```

If you always use two backslashes you will never be wrong.

Comment: I did like `if( !preg_match( '/^[\\\,.\d\pL]*$/u', $_POST['some_text'] ) ) { ... }` So to escape backslash i had to use 3 backslashes \\\. Tried with one and two, did not work. Do not understand why 3

Comment: @user2118559 the first two in the single quoted string generate one, the third is left alone (not followed by single quote or backslash). so two backslashes are inserted in the string that is passed to the regexp. Then the regexp uses the first one to escape the second, resulting in a single "real" (= to be really found in the text) backspace character. You could have used four instead (four become two, parsing the string, then the remaining two become one, parsing the regexp) like suggested correctly by this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape all backslashes like `"c:\\windows\\"`.