# Replace character with special characters

Tags: php

I have something like this :

```
$x = "#frac {2} {3}";
```

I try this code but is doesnt work:

```
$x = str_replace("#","\"",$x);
```

I want to replace # with with \ in this string. But I cant use str_replace.

any help?

Comment: Try ´$x = str_replace("#","\\",$x);´

Comment: you're escaping the quotes not the backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the # with a "
To use the backslash in a string you need to escape it.
[How do you make a string in PHP with a backslash in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764729/how-do-you-make-a-string-in-php-with-a-backslash-in-it)

```
$x = "#frac {2} {3}";
$x = str_replace("#", "\\", $x);
```