# Check for domain prefix in username login

Tags: php

How do i check for `"AD\"` in a string? If someone tries to login using the domain prefix `"AD\"` - I want the application to ignore the `"AD\"` and check for username after the first 3 characters..

I have tried:

```
if (strpos($username, "AD\\") !== false) {
    $username = substr($username, 3);
}
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Provided the value of `$username` is actually `AD\something` the code you have above should work correctly.  Inspect it via `var_dump($username);`

Comment: Though you should probably use `=== 0` instead of `!== false` because it must occur at the start of the string rather than anywhere else in the string.

Comment: Ahh yes! It works now after I changed to !== 0.  Thanks Michael

Comment: But it should also work the way you had it. http://codepad.viper-7.com/rVAz7Y  The `!== false` is not a problem (just not fully correct)

Comment: Further, using `!== 0` rather than `=== 0` can't be correct either because that would be looking for `AD\\` somewhere other than the start of the string. If that works, then `$username` must not contain the value you expect.

Comment: Hmm ... true but it doesn't work properly now without "AD\"

Comment: Sure it does. http://codepad.viper-7.com/DWrNOd If it isn't working for you, it is not because of this code snippet. This works correctly, and there may be something else interfering.

Comment: Your right, it does work.. I confused myself with using "AD\\" in the code but then entering lowercase "ad\" when logging in... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (strpos($username, "AD\\") !== false) {
```

This check the occurrence of `AD\` in **any** part of the string. So, `AD\ABC` is true, but also `ABC\AD\ABC`.

What you may want is use

```
if (strpos($username, "AD\\") === 0) {
```

To know that the username **start** with `AD\`.
Note that we are using  the `===` operator for testing the return value of `strpos`, because it returns `false` if `AD\` was not found.

**Edit**: Note however that with

```
if (strpos($username, "AD\\") === 0) {
   $username = substr($username, 3);
}
```

the user can type `AD\AD\ABC` as well, and the final result will be `AD\ABC`.
You might want to do this:

```
while(strpos($username, "AD\\") === 0) {
    $username = substr($username, 3);
}
```

to ensure that the username can not start with `AD\`

http://codepad.viper-7.com/uWC8oR

Answer (score 0):

You would need to double check what you are getting is part of the string and it has to be on the beginning of the string.

```
if (strpos($a,"AD\\") !== false)
    if (strpos($a,"AD\\") == 0)  
              echo substr($a,3);
```

Another solution would be to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the \ is recognized as an escape sequence. Therefor use ' instead of " for the string.

Moreover comparing the return value of strpos with false works due to the fact that false is defined as 0 but strpos actually returns a numeric value (the position of the occuring char/string). I'd stricly recommend making a numeric comparison here rather than a boolean.

this example works:

```
$username = 'AD\testuser';

if (strpos($username, "AD") <= 0) {
    $username = substr($username, strpos($username, "AD")+3);
    print $username;
}
else {
    print $username;
}
```

you can test it by c&p it into http://phptester.net/

for futher information on the backslashes, see: [How do you make a string in PHP with a backslash in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764729/how-do-you-make-a-string-in-php-with-a-backslash-in-it)

Comment: If someones username is "ADonald" and that person does not type in "AD\" prefix it does not work... we cannot only check for "AD" -- I need to check with the slash