# php how to print backslashes

Tags: php, string, formatting, backslash

I have an input that can contain backslashes, how can I print that string as it:

```
<?php

$input = 'B\lB\\lAn';

echo $input;
```

It prints `B\lB\lAn` instead of `B\lB\\lAn`

and `addslashes($input)` prints `B\\lB\\lAn`

how can I print `B\lB\\lAn`?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a string in PHP with a backslash in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764729/how-do-you-make-a-string-in-php-with-a-backslash-in-it)

Comment: isn't duplicate, my question is about how add that backslash dynamically, because my input is an external input that i cannot control

Answer (score 0):

PHP thinks you are trying to escape the `/` because you have 2 slashes after one other, try writing this: `////`

Comment: that's my external input 'B\lB\\lAn' i only want to print it as it, my input cannot change

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised `addslashes` doesn't just add slashes to all backslashes but that's easily accomplished:

```
<?php

$input = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', 'B\lB\\lAn');

echo $input;
```

Should output `B\lB\\lAn`.

Comment: @fj123x, I can't even fathom why it would output like that. So it prints `\\l` as `\\l` and `\\\\l` as `\\l`? I'll do a bit more reading but I can't find logic to your issue.

Comment: well, this is related with I have an application that connects with google maps api, the user creates some routes, etc and google maps returns to the client a path string like: `weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:u|p|Fy_{KrDw@vDw@pCeAhI}C\pANVh@CrAjIlAbFnAnClAvBn@t@hAbAhDnBpFlBZHlB\lCt@xA@bAOp@KrAE`CAbDSlKw@x@@h@Nd@^V`@z@`Ej@xB\\lAn@t@`@v@r...`, and I need to use that exactly string to call the http staticmaps api from the backend to retrieve an image of that route, so I get an input like `B\lB\\lAn` and I need to print it as it.