# PHP error with special chars strings

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I am trying to replace a character with another but the problem i get is they are both special characters:

```
$exe = replaceAllChars($exe, '\', '/');
```

This brakes my syntax highlighting and givers the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\User Projects\Example.php on line 16
```

How can i input these special characters as strings?

Comment: A backslash is defined with `'\\'`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4764746/3832970. And [PHP Web manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Since a backslash is used to escape with, you need to "escape the escape", doing `'\\'` to produce an actual backslash `'\'`

Answer (score 0):

Backslash (`\`) is an escape character. So to escape a backslash, use double backslash `\\`. So it should be:

```
$exe = replaceAllChars($exe, '\\', '/');
```

This means, you are escaping a backslash itself, to print it.