# Execute an application through PHP

Tags: php, exec

I want to execute an application called "svm-predict" that's in the folder "libsvm-3.22\windows" using PHP.

The syntax to run the application is:

```
svm-predict testData.test SLB.train.model SLB.out
```

I tried using the code below but it doesn't create an out file, namely SLB.out

```
<?php
    $argument = "testData.test SLB.train.model SLB.out";
    exec("C:\wamp\www\test\libsvm-3.22\windows\svm-predict $argument");
?>
```

I can't seem to find the problem.

Adding double backslash didn't solve the problem.

```
<?php
    $argument = "testData.test SLB.train.model SLB.out";
    exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\svm\\libsvm-3.22\\windows\\svm-predict $argument");
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `shell_exec()`?

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have the `execute` permission to that file from PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a string in PHP with a backslash in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764729/how-do-you-make-a-string-in-php-with-a-backslash-in-it)

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli yes, read and execute permission.

Comment: @user3409662 already changed it to exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\svm\\libsvm-3.22\\windows\\svm-predict $argument"); still doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you capture the command output and return code? You're otherwise hitting in the dark.