# eliminate 3 backslashes with stripslashes

Tags: php, wordpress, stripslashes

Out of some reasons after updating several things, on our wordpress site in the custom fields are automatically addes 3 backslashes before every apostrophe. 
**Example**: `src="abc"` will result in `src=\\\"abc\\\"`

I've got a function in functions.php where I hook into the website. Now I need to remove those backslashes. This is the orignal function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'headline_placeholder');
function headline_placeholder () {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'productheadline', true);
wp_reset_query();
}
```

This is what I tried to remove the backslashes, but its only removing 2 backslashes, not all 3.

```
function removeslashes($string)
{
    $string=implode("",explode("\\",$string));
    return stripslashes(trim($string));
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'headline_placeholder');
function headline_placeholder () {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'productheadline', true);
echo removeslashes($meta);
wp_reset_query();
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use str_replace, something like this:

```
function removesalshes($text) {
    return str_replace ( "///" , "", $text);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your idea. I changed it like the following, but its not removing any backslash. Do you know why? 

`function removeslashes($text) {
    return str_replace ( "///" , "", $text);
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'headline_placeholder');
function headline_placeholder () {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'productheadline', true);
echo removeslashes($meta);
wp_reset_query();
}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are removing forward slash. Try the following:

```
function removesalshes($text) {
    return str_replace ( '\\\' , "", $text);
}
```

Comment: yes youre right, that was a problem, but out of some reason you cant put three slashes (or any other odd number) into it, because than the following code is not working. I also tried 6 Slashes but its still one backslash left. I also tried disabling magic_quotes, but its not working. I dont know why..

Comment: back slashes have special use in php. if a back slash is followed by another back slash, then the two back slashes are treated as one slash. it is discussed in this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764746/4508593. if you are sure your text does not contain any useful slashes you can remove all slashes using: `str_replace ( '\\' , "", $text);`

Comment: ah thanks for this link!
Basically this functions works, but one of this 3 backslashes is still existing in front of every apostrophe.

Comment: are you using the addslashes function in your code. it seems your code is adding slashes to the data before it is saved to database

Comment: no - normal wordpress-site. And its only in the custom fields, which content I hook into the product pages.

Comment: try this code: `str_replace('\\"', '"', str_replace ( '\\\\\\' , "", $text);)`. it first removes the two slashes and then removes the slash from the apostrophe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148755/discussion-between-krystian-manthey-and-nadir-latif).