# How to search literal string in Mediawiki, containing a backslash?

Tags: php, search, mediawiki, literals

When using mediawiki, is there way for users to search for a literal `\` character in the content. Let's say the content contains:

```
<pre>\\FOOBAR</pre>
```

And there is a need to search for the `\\FOOBAR` (anywhere, not necessarily within a `<pre>`) but not match pages which just have "FOOBAR". I've tried searching in different combinations, but it strips out the `\` and returns undesired results.

Comment: You need to escape the backslahes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764729/how-do-you-make-a-string-in-php-with-a-backslash-in-it

Comment: @Melvin I'm referring to the Mediawiki web app front end UI by end users, not in the PHP source code.